# Issue with Spring Method interceptor

Tags: spring, aop, interceptor, spring-aop

I'm having an issue with using Spring interceptor. I've a CXF service endpoint method which I'm trying a wrap with an interceptor to do some initialization. For some reason, the interceptor is not being invoked. Here's my spring entry:

```
<jaxrs:server id="acadConnectServer" address="/rest/acadconnect3">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="acadConnectResource" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
<bean id="acadConnectResource"
    class="com.test.connectchannel.service.AcadConnectChannelResource" />
<bean id="connectResource" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="acadConnectResource" />
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>methodPointCut</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="methodPointCut"
    class="org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="advice">
        <ref local="methodInterceptor" />
    </property>
    <property name="mappedNames">
        <list>
            <value>search</value>
            <value>searchJSONP</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="methodInterceptor"
    class="com.test.connectchannel.util.ConnectChannelInterceptor">
</bean>
```

As you can see, I've a CXF endpoint class AcadConnectChannelResource which has couple of methods search and searchJSONp. I've created the Named Method Cut interceptor to intercept these two method calls and so some initialization using the custom intercetor class.But, everytime the methods are invoked, the interceptor is not being called.

Not sure what I'm missing here, any pointer will be appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: Mmmm... everything look good.  Did you try put * in the value of your mappedNames element.  If * does not work with this impl... maybe try RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor.  This one take * for sure since all my Spring pointcut use this one... let me know.   P.S if not already done... put some trace in your interceptor to see if it get in somewhere with the *.

Comment: @ Cygnusx1 Using * didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I might be entirely wrong, but don't you want

```
<ref bean="connectResource" />
```

instead of

```
<ref bean="acadConnectResource" />
```

in your `<jaxrs:server>`? You're proxying the resource, but using the raw resource instead of the proxy.

Comment: I tried that too, but got org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException caused by javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's wrong. It might mean that you have other problems elsewhere. I don't know CXF, but if you post a stack trace, someone might be able to point out what's wrong or steer you in the right direction.